# Spring MVC AngularJS JPA example - Unable to call web service

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, jpa-2.0

I am developing `Spring MVC AngularJS` example. I've simply taken a code from link: **https://github.com/sivaprasadreddy/sivalabs-blog-samples-code/tree/master/springmvc-angular-crud**. I am able to login using siva@gmail.com/siva successfully, but when I'm accessing logout, user profile, setting etc, nothing is happening. Please guide what is missing here.

login.jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@include file="taglib.jsp" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
<base href="${rootUrl}">
<%@ include file="assets.jspf" %>  
</head>
<body>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
        <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
             <div class="alert alert-danger">
                 Invalid UserName and Password.
             </div>
         </c:if>
         <c:if test="${param.logout != null}">
             <div class="alert alert-success">
                 You have been logged out.
             </div>
         </c:if>    
         </div>  

     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
            <h2>User Login Form</h2>
            <form:form id="loginForm" method="post" action="login" modelAttribute="user" 
        class="form-horizontal" role="form" cssStyle="width: 800px; margin: 0 auto;">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 control-label">UserName*</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="UserName" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password*</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
            </div>
          </div>
           <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
              New User? <a href="register">Register</a>
            </div>
          </div>

        </form:form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

register.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@include file="taglib.jsp"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Create User</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#registrationForm").submit(function( event ) {
          var userName = $.trim($("#userName").val());
          var password = $.trim($("#password").val());
          var firstName = $.trim($("#firstName").val());
          var email = $.trim($("#email").val());

          if(userName == '' || password == '' || firstName == '' || email == ''){
                alert("Please enter all mandatory fields");
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
          }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
        <c:if test="${ERROR != null }">
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <p>${ERROR}
            </div>
        </c:if>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
            <h2>User Registration Form</h2>
            <form:form id="registrationForm" method="post" action="register"
                modelAttribute="user" cssStyle="width: 800px; margin: 0 auto;"
                class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="userName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">UserName*</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName"
                            class="form-control" placeholder="UserName" />
                        <form:errors path="userName" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password*</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password"
                            class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
                        <form:errors path="password" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email*</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="Email" />
                        <form:errors path="email" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="firstName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">FirstName*</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName"
                            class="form-control" placeholder="FirstName" />
                        <form:errors path="firstName" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="lastName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">LastName</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName"
                            class="form-control" placeholder="LastName" />
                        <form:errors path="lastName" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="dob" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date Of
                        Birth</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" id="dob" name="dob" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="dd-MM-yyyy" />
                        <form:errors path="dob" cssClass="text-danger" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
                        Already Registered? <a href="login">Login</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form:form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

welcome.jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<%@ include file="taglib.jsp" %>

<html lang="en" ng-app="usersApp">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Spring MVC Angular Tutorials : Forum</title>
<%@ include file="assets.jspf"%>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="${rootUrl}home">My DashBoard</a>
            </div>


            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> My Account </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                            <li><a href="${rootUrl}myAccount"><i
                                    class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> User Profile</a></li>
                            <li><a href="${rootUrl}changePwd"><i
                                    class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i> Settings</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="${rootUrl}logout">Logout</a></li>
                        </ul> <!-- /.dropdown-user --></li>
                    <li><a href="${rootUrl}logout">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 sidebar">
                <div class="list-group">
                    <span class="list-group-item active">Personal Data</span> <a
                        href="#phonebook" class="list-group-item">PhoneBook</a> <a
                        href="#events" class="list-group-item">Events</a> <span
                        class="list-group-item active">Settings</span> <a href="#"
                        class="list-group-item">Configuration</a>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9 " ng-controller="UserCtrl">

                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="20px;">Id</th>
                            <th width="100px;">FirstName</th>
                            <th width="100px;">LastName</th>
                            <th width="150px;">Email</th>
                            <th width="100px;">Edit / Delete</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="user in userList">
                            <td>{{user.id}}</td>
                            <td>{{user.firstName}}</td>
                            <td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
                            <td>{{user.email}}</td>
                            <td><span style="cursor: pointer;"
                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"
                                ng-click="handleEditUser(user)"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp; <span
                                style="cursor: pointer;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"
                                ng-click="handleDeleteUser(user)"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Edit User</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">

                        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputId" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Id</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputId"
                                        placeholder="Id" ng-model="editUser.id">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputFirstName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">FirstName</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName"
                                        placeholder="FirstName" ng-model="editUser.firstName">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputLastName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">LastName</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLastName"
                                        placeholder="LastName" ng-model="editUser.lastName">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail"
                                        placeholder="Email" ng-model="editUser.email">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"
                                        ng-click="handleUpdateUser(editUser)">Save</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

ContactController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users/{userId}/contacts/")
public class ContactController{
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value="", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Contact> findAll(@PathVariable("userId") int userId) {
        return userService.findUserContacts(userId);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{contactId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public Contact findContact(@PathVariable("userId") int userId, @PathVariable("contactId") int contactId) {
        return userService.findUserContact(userId, contactId);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public Contact createContact(@PathVariable("userId") int userId, Contact contact) {
        return userService.saveUserContact(contact);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    public Contact updateContact(@PathVariable("userId") int userId, Contact contact) {
        return userService.saveUserContact(contact);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{contactId}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void deleteContact(@PathVariable("userId") int userId, @PathVariable("contactId") int contactId) {
        userService.deleteUserContact(userId, contactId);
    }
}
```

UserController.java

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginForm(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String registrationForm(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "register";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String handleRegistration(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult errors, Model model){
        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            return "register";
        }
        try {
            userService.createUser(user);
            return "redirect:login";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            model.addAttribute("ERROR", e.getMessage());
            return "register";
        }
    }
}
```

assets.jspf

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${rootUrl}resources/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${rootUrl}resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${rootUrl}resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${rootUrl}resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="resources/angularjs/angular.js"></script>
<script src="resources/angularjs/angular-resource.js"></script>

<script src="${rootUrl}resources/js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="${rootUrl}resources/js/services.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="${rootUrl}resources/css/styles.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${rootUrl}resources/js/app.js"></script>
```

taglib.jsp:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"  prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" prefix="c" %>
<c:url var="rootUrl" value="/"/>
```

**Please let me know if You need any info.**
Screen shots of UI:
[image]

If I call any tab it gives nothing why?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

not seeing any handelar for `/logout`. Create a controller method to handle this request

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET/POST)
public String registrationForm(Model model){
   //your logic     
   return "register";
   //or return "redirect:/login" 
}
```

Comment: Also UserProfile, Setting tabs are not working. Why ?

Comment: same case i assume